# Checking HTTP status codes in groovy

Tags: rest, groovy, soapui

I have created a `RESTful` service and I am testing it in `SOAPUI` project.
In a test case I want  to verify the `HTTP` response status codes in `groovy` script.

I have tried using the following:

```
def value = messageExchange.responseHeaders["#status#"]

assert value==200
```

But it always gives the error and doesn't validates.*(The test I am using does returns 200 status code, but I don't know how to put the groovy correctly)*

Can anyone plz guide me. I dont want to perform `GET` operation in the groovy. I am performing `GET` separately using soapui and I just want to test the status codes.

Comment: Similar questions that have been asked earlier:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6330449/how-to-add-assertion-for-http-204-content-in-rest

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16662959/how-to-test-the-response-content-type-using-soap-ui

Comment: @kunal Thanks Kunal! It solved my purpose :)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This is going to be very useful for future use. I did some searching and found a post regarding this at the [SoapUI forum](http://forum.loadui.org/viewtopic.php?f=1&t=1800#p6696).

I tested it with an HTTP step (sorry, I don't have any rest services to use) and it works well. Luckily, SoapUI handles most all requests the same way so it should work for you as well.

And the raw code:

```
def groovyUtils = new com.eviware.soapui.support.GroovyUtils( context )
def httpResponseHeaders = context.testCase.testSteps["testName"].testRequest.response.responseHeaders
def httpStatus = httpResponseHeaders["#status#"]
def httpStatusCode = (httpStatus =~ "[1-5]\\d\\d")[0]

log.info("HTTP status code: " + httpStatusCode)
```

Comment: Thanks. This helped me. Works the same way for Restfull service as well.

Answer (score 1):

For anyone working in ReadyAPI, the solution has changed a bit since 2014.

```
def httpResponseHeaders = testRunner.testCase.getTestStepByName("testName").testRequest.response.responseHeaders
def httpStatus = httpResponseHeaders["#status#"]
def httpStatusCode = (httpStatus =~ "[1-5]\\d\\d")[0]

log.info("HTTP status code: " + httpStatusCode)
```

This swaps the `context` variable for the `testRunner` variable, both of which are exposed by ReadyAPI.

[ReadyAPI Groovy docs](https://support.smartbear.com/readyapi/docs/functional/steps/groovy.html)